# how can i add new row in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, php-5.6, phpspreadsheet

i have one small project [Billing Account] contains some math operations / values like [+/*-%]..
with deep search a lot of sites advise phpspreadsheet , i started to learn how use it by tutorials.

Q: how i add new row?

for example : when i click save button program will be save another record in 
new row.

### Code:

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet; 
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

require_once __DIR__ . '/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/Bootstrap.php';


$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name">
    Age:<input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php

$spreadsheet->getProperties()
->setCreator('root');

// New Worksheet
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('MySheet');


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

 $sheet->setCellValue('A1',$name);
 $sheet->setCellValue('B1',$age);

$Writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$Writer->save('test.xlsx');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is insertNewRowBefore, you need a Worksheet class instance which is what you use most of the time to manipulate a particular active sheet.
I don't realy know what else you need but follow [this API docs](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Worksheet/Worksheet.html#method_insertNewColumnBefore)

If you just want to add a value into a cell, simply use:

```
$cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(colNumber(int), rowNumber(int));
$sheet->setCellValue('e.g A1', $cell->getValue());
```

Then again, explore the api, spreadsheet works in a rather weird manner.

Comment: hey Mr Daniel, thanks for replay, i have HTML form with php using POST method, i collect data coming from inputs to insert into excel file ,i just look for simple way to save data in test.xlsx without delete old entries.

Comment: If that is the case check out my edited version of the answer.

Comment: You can omit the `$cell` line and pass a scalar to `setCellValue`.